# Retrieving object data from a service in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to retrieve data from my service function, but am running into issues. My LandingPage component code, shown below, sends a keystroke to my service function, which then returns an object full of data.

But I cannot get the service object to return to my LandingPage. Here is how I create my service:

**task.service.ts**

```
  addKey(keystroke) {
    const query = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=";
    fetch(query + key + '&language=en-US&query=' + keystroke)
      .then((show) => {
        show.json().then((obj) => {
          // grab the items we want from the response
          let resultItems = obj.results.map((show, index) => {
            return {
              id: show.id,
              poster: show.poster_path,
              rating: show.vote_average,
              backdrop: show.backdrop_path,
            };
          });
          // return our newly formed object
          return { data: resultItems }
        });
      });
  }
```

Here is where I am trying to receive the service data, in my:

**landingpage.component.ts**

```
  getKey(keystroke) {
      this.TaskService.addKey(keystroke)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.shows = res.data; // trying to receive service info here
        });
  }
```

When I try to build, I receive the following error in my LandingPage component:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

I've tried using map instead of subscribe, but it returns a similar error.

How can I send the object result from my service, to my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `return` in your service method, I've also changed to using `http` from our discussion in the comments:

```js
  addKey(keystroke): Observable<any> {
    const query = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=";
    return this.http.get(query + key + '&language=en-US&query=' + keystroke)
      .map(show => {
        show.json().then((obj) => {
          // grab the items we want from the response
          let resultItems = obj.results.map((show, index) => {
            return {
              id: show.id,
              poster: show.poster_path,
              rating: show.vote_average,
              backdrop: show.backdrop_path,
            };
          });
          // return our newly formed object
          return { data: resultItems }
        });
      });
  }
```

If you really want to use fetch you can if you:

- Set the method return signature to `Promise<any>`
- Use `then` instead of `map` in the service
- Use `then` instead of `subscribe` in the component

Comment: Thanks for the response! This still gives me the same error though, not sure why. Also, I'm just trying to return { data: resultItems} to the component

Comment: you possibly need the method return signature as well (answer updated to include this) Is this a runtime error or a transpile time error?

Comment: thanks! This is a transpile time error, I think the observable may be the right direction, still having a bit of trouble, seen here: http://i.imgur.com/2HxvyNQ.png

Comment: replace `then` with `map` (as shown in my, now, updated answer). I would recommend using angular's [Http](https://angular.io/guide/http) instead of fetch but it's up to you :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I might have to use angular's http, because even though I imported map, I'm getting "property map does not exist on type 'Promise<Response>'. I'll try out using http

Comment: I've added a section at the bottom for how to use promise (haven't tested it, might need tweaking) if you want to stick with fetch, but Angular's Http is a good way to go

Comment: I tested your fetch solution, and it works! However, yes, I'll be switching it over to Http like you suggested. Thanks, I'm new to Angular, so best practice advice is very valuable!